# Почему незабудка?

Tags: этимология

Думаю, все знают цветов незабудку. Обычный, ничем не примечательный голубой цветочек.
А почему, собственно, он называется "незабудка"? Как он связан с памятью?
Или это что из так называемого языка цветов - искусства составления букетов, где каждый цветок несет какой-то смысл?

Answer (score 3):

"Милый незабудка цветик! Видишь, друг мой, я, стеня, Еду от тебя, мой светик: Не забудь меня" (Державин).

Название цветка - интернациональная европейская языковая калька.

Есть основания думать, что его еще не было в русском языке первой трети XVIII в. (цветок назывался миронник, дубровник, горлянка, дубравная вероника). Но в последней четверти XVIII в. слово незабудка уже вошло в литературно-языковый обиход. Об этом свидетельствует употребление этого слова в языке сочинений Державина, Карамзина, Дмитриева.

Интересно, что у всех христианских народов этот цветок носит одинаковое по смыслу название.  Предполагают, что истоком этого может быть древнегреческий миф  о богине цветов Флоре, которая одаривала все растения именами, а про крошечную голубую незабудку позабыла. Зато потом вместе с парадоксальным названием она наградила обиженный цветок еще и чудесной силой: возвращать память тем людям, которые забывают своих близких или свою родину.

http://myphs.jimdo.com/2014/05/09/незабудка/

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, этот цветок высаживали на могилках кладбищ, и когда за этими могилками переставали ухаживать, они приходили в упадок: сгнивал и разваливался крест, холмик сглаживался и зарастал, незабудки же оставались единственным напоминанием о том, что в данном месте кто-то захоронен. Это моя версия, подкреплённая лишь собственными наблюдениями.

Answer (score 1):

Название цветка с таким же буквальным смыслом (не забудь меня) встречается в других языках (немецкий, французский, английский и др.). Обычно объяснения приводят из немецкого фольклора. По одной версии Создатель раздавал сотворённым цветам названия, по другой - цвета. В обоих случаях  "и меня не забудь" исходило от неприметного цветочка. Соответственно, ему досталось имя ("так и будешь зваться") или остатки цвета. По другой немецкой легенде (15 век) таковы были последние слова рыцаря, упавшего в тяжелых доспехах в воду при попытке сорвать провожаемой даме эти цветочки (она их носила в память о нём)..